# In an Azure key vault can i retrieve all versions of a secret by just secret name?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I will be storing a value in Azure Key vault and when i retrieve it i want to retrieve all the previous versions too. I won't know how many previous versions there will be, could be just one.

i have looked into getSecret C# method and i can get the latest version if i don't specify the version or a specific version if i know.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.getsecret?view=azure-java-stable

Is there a way to get all of them in a list?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.listpropertiesofsecretversions?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_security_keyvault_secrets_SecretClient_listPropertiesOfSecretVersions_java_lang_String_) iterates over each secret by each page and calls SecretClient#getSecret(String, String). This will return the secret with the corresponding version's value.

```
secretClient.listPropertiesOfSecretVersions("secretName", new Context(key1, value2))
             .iterableByPage().forEach(resp -> {
                 System.out.printf("Got response headers . Url: %s, Status code: %d %n",
                     resp.getRequest().getUrl(), resp.getStatusCode());
                 resp.getItems().forEach(value -> {
                     KeyVaultSecret secretWithValue = secretClient.getSecret(value.getName(), value.getVersion());
                     System.out.printf("Received secret's version with name %s and value %s",
                         secretWithValue.getName(), secretWithValue.getValue());
                 });
             });
```

---

**For SDK:**

[listPropertiesOfSecretVersions(String name)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.listpropertiesofsecretversions?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_security_keyvault_secrets_SecretClient_listPropertiesOfSecretVersions_java_lang_String_)

```
for (SecretProperties secret : secretClient.listPropertiesOfSecretVersions("secretName")) {
     KeyVaultSecret secretWithValue = secretClient.getSecret(secret.getName(), secret.getVersion());
     System.out.printf("Received secret's version with name %s and value %s",
         secretWithValue.getName(), secretWithValue.getValue());
 }
```

The you can use [getSecret(String vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclient.getsecret?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_keyvault_KeyVaultClient_getSecret_String_String_String_)

**For REST API:**

You can use [Get Secret Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecretversions/getsecretversions).

You can list all versions of the specified secret using

```
GET {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/versions?api-version=7.1
```

It'll return a list of secrets along with a link to the next page of secrets.

Then you can use [Get Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret)

```
GET {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}?api-version=7.1
```

**For CLI:**

If you use [list-versions cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-list-versions), you can do it as

```
az keyvault secret list-versions [--id]
                                 [--maxresults]
                                 [--name]
                                 [--subscription]
                                 [--vault-name]
```

Then you can get the secret using [az keyvault secret show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-show)

```
az keyvault secret show [--id]
                        [--name]
                        [--subscription]
                        [--vault-name]
                        [--version]
```

Comment: This is the right way.